# Using XSLT in XML File

Tags: xslt

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I have a simple XML file which contain data like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XmlStyle.xslt"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

and my XSLT File Contain Data like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <html>
        <body>
          <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
          <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Artist</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and now my problem is that when I run my XML file it shows result like this

```
My CD CollectionTitleArtistMy CD CollectionTitleArtistMy CD CollectionTitleArtist
  My CD CollectionTitleArtistMy CD CollectionTitleArtist
    My CD CollectionTitleArtistMy CD CollectionTitleArtistEmpire BurlesqueMy CD CollectionTitleArtist
    My CD CollectionTitleArtistMy CD CollectionTitleArtistBob DylanMy CD CollectionTitleArtist
    My CD CollectionTitleArtistMy CD CollectionTitleArtistUSAMy CD CollectionTitleArtist
    My CD CollectionTitleArtistMy CD CollectionTitleArtistColumbiaMy CD CollectionTitleArtist
    My CD CollectionTitleArtistMy CD CollectionTitleArtist10.90My CD CollectionTitleArtist
    My CD CollectionTitleArtistMy CD CollectionTitleArtist1985My CD CollectionTitleArtist
  My CD CollectionTitleArtist
```

What should I do to get the right result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange result, but the stylesheet is much more strange. Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <body>
          <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
          <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Artist</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template produces a correct table when used with a compliant XSLT processor. Note also that it is correct to use XML as output method even if you want html. But you can omit it, as XML is the default output method.

Also make sure to exploit template rule pattern. Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/cd">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="title|artist"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title|artist">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many Thanks now i have got the right result can u please tell me the cause of problem?

Comment: The problem is the template match pattern you used and also the final copy statement. See my answer to know about how to apply template rules. Also make sure to accept the answer by selecting the green mark at the top left.

Comment: The `match="node()|@*"` pattern matches any node and attribute. In the last instruction you copy the current matched node and then apply templates to `node()|@*`. The result is the recursive behavior you see in your result output.

Answer (score 0):

The output method is XML. Change it to HTML:

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
```

It should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"> 
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>      
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
      <html> 
        <body> 
          <h2>My CD Collection</h2> 
          <table border="1"> 
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32"> 
              <th>Title</th> 
              <th>Artist</th> 
            </tr> 
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd"> 
              <tr> 
                <td> 
                  <xsl:value-of select="title"/> 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                  <xsl:value-of select="artist"/> 
                </td> 
              </tr> 
            </xsl:for-each> 
          </table> 
        </body> 
      </html>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks For helping But now i have got another problem my data is repeating can you please tell me how can i stop to repeat data

Comment: Did you try removing the `<xsl:copy` section?

Comment: yes i try but still it s repeating the data Two times can you help me?

Comment: Many Thanks now i have got the right result can u please tell me the cause of problem?

Comment: As empo said, The `match="node()|@*"` pattern matches any node and attribute. In the last instruction you copy the current matched node and then apply templates to `node()|@*`. The result is the recursive behavior you see in your result output.

Comment: If you're satisfied, please remember to mark the answer. Glad you got it working.

Comment: The immediate cause of the problem is as James Johnson describes. The deeper cause of the problem seems to be that you are trying to write code in a language whose behaviour you do not understand. I would recommend that you spend a day or two reading a good book about XSLT before you try to write any more code.